# AudioKit 4.2.3 Crash Microphone Frequency Analysis Swift 4.1

Tags: swift, audiokit, frequency-analysis

I just updated to the latest AudioKit version 4.2.3 and Swift 4.1 I'm getting a crash at audiokit.start() that I can't decipher. Please lmk if you need more of the error code.

AURemoteIO::IOThread (21): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x100900000)

FYI I am also using AVAudioRecorder to record the microphone input to file and playing it with AVKit AVAudioPlayer later on in the ViewController. However, since I did not get this crash before updating I do not believe those factors are responsible - but something with the tracker input.

```
import UIKit
import Speech
import AudioKit

class RecordVoiceViewController: UIViewController {

    var tracker: AKFrequencyTracker!
    var silence: AKBooster!
    var mic: AKMicrophone!

    let noteFrequencies = [16.35, 17.32, 18.35, 19.45, 20.6, 21.83, 23.12, 24.5, 25.96, 27.5, 29.14, 30.87]
    let noteNamesWithSharps = ["C", "C♯","D","D♯","E","F","F♯","G","G♯","A","A♯","B"]
    let noteNamesWithFlats = ["C", "D♭","D","E♭","E","F","G♭","G","A♭","A","B♭","B"]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
        mic = AKMicrophone()
        tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(mic, hopSize: 200, peakCount: 2000)
        silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)
    }

    func startAudioKit(){
        AudioKit.output = self.silence
        do {
            try AudioKit.start()
        } catch {
            AKLog("Something went wrong.")
        }
    }
}
```

What's interesting is when I initialize the tracker without the hopSize and peakCount, like:

```
  tracker = AKFrequencyTracker.init(mic)
```

it does not crash, however it also doesn't return the correct frequency. I'm super thankful for any help. Thanks!!!

Comment: After testing over here, I don't find anything wrong, if you want to share your project, even privately, I'll have a closer look.

Comment: Thanks @AureliusProchazka !  Sent you an email. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced exactly the same issue, but finally found a temporary solution. 
All you need to do is to **add an additional layer between** `AKMicrophone` **and** `AKFrequencyTracker`, in my case it was `AKHighPassFilter`.

Here's the code that works properly:

```
let microphone = AKMicrophone()
let filter = AKHighPassFilter(microphone, cutoffFrequency: 200, resonance: 0)
let tracker = AKFrequencyTracker(filter)
let silence = AKBooster(tracker, gain: 0)

AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true
AudioKit.output = silence
try! AudioKit.start()
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Comment: Thanks. But that's what I already had. The newest version of Audiokit fixed it.